# How to pass parameters of my external C# code to the Unity3D exe file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `C#` solution that solves a dynamic problem, I want to simulate the motion of masses in a real-time manner. I prepared a `Unity3D` exe file with some objects which are controlled using internal scripts of the Unity and it works internally which is not useful for me. in this respect, in my external `C#` code, after problem solution, I called the exe file using `Process.Start();`.

The problem is that I can't pass the position values to `Unity3D` process. How is it possible to send my `C#` parameters to the running Unity process?

I read so many tutorials in which Unity gets the input from keyboard or mouse or other devices but I want to send my code parameters to Unity as an input.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is putting the c# script into the Unity solution no option?

Comment: if you are constantly trying to get updated values, normally you would poll from inside unity something, so, a web page with xml/json/heck even text, a database, etc to look for the new info

Comment: Can you create a dll from your C# solution and import it to Unity ?

Comment: @derHugo  it is a large solution with so many classes and GUI forms. I want to add visualization as an option for the user.

Comment: @BugFinder Sure I can read for example from csv files but I was wondering if visualization tool (in my case Unity) could get variables directly from the main code.

Comment: @PierreBaret I don't know if it is possible because I want to add visualization as an option to the existing GUI form. I dont want to force the user to watch the visualization.

Comment: Well you can have it ping web data, host sockets, all sorts, so its really up to you to decide how you wanna pump that data in

Answer (score 5):

Use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to get the arguments.

In Unity

```
class YourScript : Monobehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
       string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    }
}
```

Your code

```
Process.Start("your_program.exe", "arg1 arg2 ...");
```

Comment: i got the impression the OP wants on going data to be passed not just at the start of the unity process

Comment: Yeah the question sounds to be more about continous communication

Comment: Exactly I want a continuous connection between my code and the unity in each time step.

Comment: @Datav, ok, I think this is a pure C# problem about IPC, try [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/windows-communication-foundation-services-and-wcf-data-services-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) and [WCF for unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Wcf)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just parse data when you launch with arguments, using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` is good enough.

If you need to send and receive data both ways (or one way), you can use memory mapped files ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)).
Example:

```cs
//creates a memory map file in system memory with 1024 bytes of space
var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("memory", 1024);
var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
//writes 3.14 as a double to the memory at position 8
accessor.Write(8, 3.14);

//reads the double from position 8
double pi = accessor.Read<double>(8);
```

This is certainly doable, I use this method of communication between my network process and the game engine in order to avoid assembly reloads when the editor compiles scripts during run time so that I dont lose any connections.

Comment: Thanks @Phill Damaskin this worked for me when I use float format for the parameter, but I must use double format. I used exactly the syntax:                double pi = accessor.Read<double>(8);                  but there is a error that says: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Structure' of 'UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.Read<T>(long, out T)'

Answer (score 0):

and also there is another problem! the code I am using in Unity is:

void Update()

```
{

        //reads the double from position 1
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("memory"))
        {
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
            {
                accessor.Read(1, out float omegay);
                float omegayy = Convert.ToSingle(omegay);
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, omegayy, 0) * Time.deltaTime);

            }
        }
}
```

my parameter (omegay) is a negative value, but in unity animates it as a positive number!